# jQuery hide if either div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 `div`s that are initially hidden

```
<div id="whistle" style="display:none;">
<div id="lean" style="display:none;">
```

I also have a `div` that is visible

```
<div id="me" style="display:block">
```

I have jQuery code that allows only the `#whistle` or `#lean` divs to be open at once, their buttons will hide the other.

I currently have code that also hides the `#me` div, but I would now like the `#me` div to open back up when both `#whistle` and `#lean` are closed.

If you want to see the site, the link is maxdev.tk

The jQuery code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#calc").click(function(){
        $("#whistle").hide(600);
        $("#lean").toggle(900);
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#whi").click(function(){
        $("#lean").hide(600);
        $("#whistle").toggle(900);
});
});
```

Comment: Can you please add your JavaScript code to the question.

Comment: What problem are you having when you try to open the `#me` block?

Comment: To @RoryMcCrossan I added the jQuery to the question.

Comment: @Barmar I don't have any code that can reopen the `#me`

Comment: `$("#me").show()` will do it, what's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar I don't want it to be visible when the `#whistle` or `#lean` are open, and `.toggle()` could open it up again if both buttons are clicked

Comment: I understand that. Use an `if` statement to decide when to open it. This is beginner programming.\

Comment: @Barmar Well I am a beginner, and I was asking for an `if` statement code

Comment: SO is not a "write it for me" site. You should try to write it yourself, and when you can't get it working you post what you tried. Then we'll show you where you went wrong, and you'll learn from your mistake.

Comment: I used SO already to look for some JavaScript code, and even found some that I thought would work, but they are did nothing for me.

Comment: Find a fully working example in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to solve it. Find it also as a pen at the end of this post.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function callback() {
    if( $('#whistle').hasClass('hidden') && $('#lean').hasClass('hidden') ) {
          $('#me').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
          $('#me').addClass('hidden');
    }
  }
  $('button[data-for=whistle]').on('click', function() {
    $('#whistle').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('#lean').addClass('hidden');
    callback();
  });
  $('button[data-for=lean]').on('click', function() {
    $('#lean').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('#whistle').addClass('hidden');
    callback();
  });
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-for="whistle">Whistle</button>
<button data-for="lean">Lean</button>
<div id="whistle" class="hidden">Whistle!</div>
<div id="lean" class="hidden">Lean!</div>
<div id="me">Me!</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNJrwe

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Unfortunately, it doesn't work right. If you don't mind checking it out, I made a pen here: http://codepen.io/maxrosen/pen/yNJWPb

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't reopen `#me`, and it doesn't open `#whistle` and `#lean` cannot be toggled more than once.

Comment: Well, you will have to invest *some* work yourself. So try to understand the working example, what is different to your code and learn to adapt it to your needs!

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to the end of whatever buttons' click function.

```
if( !$('#whistle').is(':visible') && !$('#lean').is(':visible') ) {
      $('#me').css("display","block"); // or use .show();
} else {
      $('#me').css("display","none"); // or use .hide();
}
```

Comment: I have used your code to construct a similarly working example in my answer.